# ignore Field File with jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

this is my form and validation jQuery, but in the UI this show in the file upload (multiples) the mensagem "enter no more than 3 characters.". I think the problem is the property `maxlength="3"` in the file Field.

How I remove the validation for this field?

```
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="main_table">
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">@Resources.Registo.nome</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("FullName", (Model != null ? Model.FullName : string.Empty), new { @class = "width250" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">@Resources.Registo.email</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("Email", (Model != null ? Model.Email : string.Empty), new { @class = "width250" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">@Resources.Registo.exemploFotos</td>
                    <td><input type="file" name="fileUpload" class="multi" accept="jpeg|jpg" maxlength="3" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr><td colspan="2"><a class="button" onclick="$('#FormToValidate').valid() == true ? get_form(this).submit() : false" id="validateAndSubmitBtn" ><span>@Resources.Global.btnSubmit</span></a></td></tr>
         </table>



$().ready(function () {
        // validate signup form on keyup and submit
        $("#FormToValidate").validate({

            rules: {

                FullName: {
                    required: true
                },
                Email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                FullName: {
                    required: "@Resources.Registo.requiredFullName"
                },
                Email: {
                    required: "@Resources.Registo.requiredEmail",
                    email: "@Resources.Registo.emailValid"
                }
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Wheel I solute this with a workaround (bullshit) in validation I put the mensage for fileUpload maxlenght = ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `ignore` parameter:

```
$("#FormToValidate").validate({
    rules: {
        FullName: {
            required: true
        },
        Email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        FullName: {
            required: "@Resources.Registo.requiredFullName"
        },
        Email: {
            required: "@Resources.Registo.requiredEmail",
            email: "@Resources.Registo.emailValid"
        }
    },
    ignore: "input[type='file']"
});
```

You can use any valid jQuery selector for the parameter should you prefer.